# PHP raising error when parsing regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP function to validate e-mail fields. In my PHP file, I receive below error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '_' in C:\xampp\htdocs\validator.inc.php on line 28
```

My PHP file is:

```
<?php
define("EMAIL_MASK", "^[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~])*@[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+$");

(...)

function isEmailValid($email)
{
    return !empty($email) && preg_match(EMAIL_MASK, $email); <---- This is the line raising the error
}

(...)

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to put the [PHP regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
define("EMAIL_MASK", "~^[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}\~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}\~])*@[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+$~");
                      |                                                                                                                          |
```

Comment: you need to escape `~`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Also in character classes?

Comment: @hakre: yes also in character classes.

Comment: @hakre yep, once it finds the next `~` symbol, then it considers it as an end delimiter. So we need to escape `~`, even when the symbol is present within the character class.

Comment: Many thanks! I forgot to put the escape character.